# Need help refactoring this jquery snippet

Tags: jquery

I'm almost embarrassed to say that I can't figure out a better way to do this. Can someone help me with refactoring this code? I tried doing a few "or" operators in one match function, but it didn't seem to take em.

```
$('.ui-icon-pencil, .ui-icon-check, .ui-icon-close, .ui-icon-trash').hover(function(e) {          

    console.log($(this).attr('class'));

    optionsClass = 'ui-icon-pencil';
    confirmClass = 'ui-icon-check';
    closeClass = 'ui-icon-close';
    deleteClass = 'ui-icon-trash';

    icon = $(this).attr('class').match(optionsClass);

    if(icon == null) {
    icon = $(this).attr('class').match(confirmClass);
    }
    if(icon == null) {
    icon = $(this).attr('class').match(closeClass);
    }
    if(icon == null) {
    icon = $(this).attr('class').match(deleteClass);
    }

    console.log('icon = '+icon);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.ui-icon-pencil, .ui-icon-check, .ui-icon-close, .ui-icon-trash').hover(function(e) {          

    var icon = $(this).attr('class').match(/ui-icon-(?:pencil|check|close|trash)/)[0]
    console.log('icon = '+icon);

});
```

Comment: `.match()` returns an array of matches found, [0] returns the whole match found.

Answer (score 2):

When you utilise a RegExp, do it in the right way:

```
$('.ui-icon-pencil, .ui-icon-check, .ui-icon-close, .ui-icon-trash').hover(function(e) {
    var icon = /\bui-icon-(?:pencil|check|close|trash)\b/.exec(this.className);
    if (icon) { // If a match is found
        icon = icon[0];
    }
    console.log('icon = ' + icon);
});
```

- `this.className` holds a (white-space separated) list of class names
- `/ui-icon- ... /` is a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) literal.
- [`regex.exec(input_string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) is equivalent, but neater than `input_string.match(regex)`.

When a match is found, `icon` will be an array in the following format:

```
[full match, group1, group2, ..., groupN]
```

To see the full match without the separate groups, use `icon[0]` (first element of `icon` array).

The [`string.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) converts the first argument to a RegExp. Generally, `regex.exec` is preferred over `string.match`, because the latter method would fail if the input is not a string (unexpected?).

Explanation of my RegEx: `\b` matches a word boundary. `(?:pencil|check|close|trash)` is a dereferenced RegEx group, which matches `"pencil"`, `"check"`, `"close"` or `"trash"`.

Comment: Can you explain what this does?

Comment: @Catfish I have added references + a brief explanation at the bottom of my answer. Are you familiar with Regular expressions?

Comment: This doesn't quite work. It returns things like `icon = ui-icon-pencil,pencil`. I need just `ui-icon-pencil`.

Comment: It's an array. icon[0] will give you the first element.

Comment: @Catfish Updated answer with more explanation, plus `[0]`.